# Is there a way to pass command line arguments to custom entry point (C / C++)

Tags: c, command-line

I used -Wl,-e to change the entry point of a C program, is there a way to still get command line arguments?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm working on mac, but I don't really have a 'target OS'. This is not a real world problem, I'm just interested to know.

Comment: The short answer is that it can be done, but the exact way to do so varies with the OS. For example, on Windows you'd call `GetCommandLine`. On most Unix-like systems, you have externals named `_argc` and `_argv` that corresponds to `argc`/`argv` that `main` receives.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I tried on my mac, seems like _argc and _argv are not globals. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Globals like `_argc`/`_argv` are provided by the compiler's runtime and thus require the compiler's default entry point to set them up. If you use your own entry point, you are bypassing all runtime initializations, so you will have to resort to platform-specific APIs to access the command-line parameters (`GetCommandLine()` on Windows, read from `/proc/self/cmdline` on Linux, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That makes sense, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Globals like `_argc`/`_argv` are provided by the compiler's runtime and thus require the compiler's default entry point to set them up. If you use your own entry point, you are bypassing all runtime initializations, so you will have to resort to platform-specific APIs to access the command-line parameters (`GetCommandLine()` on Windows, read from `/proc/self/cmdline` on Linux, etc).
                    – Remy Lebeau